# Spark Scala applying schema to RDD gives Scala match error

Tags: scala, switch-statement

I'm reading a file column by column and making it as a row and I will have to insert that into a table for which applying the schema to convert to a df. I have an integer value 2146411835(within int range) when I try to apply the schema with Integer, I get scala.MatchError: 2146411835 (of class java.lang.Integer). Any inputs?

Thanks,
Ash

Comment: Read this to ask proper question - [Ask]

Comment: This looks like a very code specific issue and is most probably caused by some problem in your code. We will need to see the code the figure out the problem.